# SQL Server Database Connection String

Tags: c#, sql-server, mono, sqlclient

I'm trying to write a program that will fetch data from a SQL Server database. The program is written on top of the .NET platform using C#. Furthermore, the program will be running on a Linux host (with mono). The problem that I am faced with is connecting to the database from the Linux machine, all of my code works fine from a windows host (since the server uses windows authentication), so my question is this: how can I connect to/authenticate with the SQL Server instance?

I've looked at http://www.mono-project.com/SQLClient, and it says to use a string similar to this: `"Server=MyServer;Database=pubs;User ID=MyWindowsDomain\\MyWindowsUserid;Password=MyWindowsPassword;Integrated Security=SSPI"` but that is not working. Is there maybe something I can do on the server (not likely that I'll be allowed to, but as a last resort)?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the connection string you are using and are there any errors when you try to connect?

Comment: The only error is that it cannot authenticate.

Comment: The mono link says "However, if you want to use NT Authentication, you must trully be on an NT/2000/2003 Domain."

Comment: I somehow missed that =\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As A. DIMO says, you cannot authenticate using integrated security on *NIX.  It's not a windows box.

In your SQL Server Management studio, create a login that uses SQL Server authentication and not Windows Authentication.  Ensure it has the necessary writes on the database in question.

Next, remove the `Integrated Security=SSPI` part of the connection string.  That should do the trick.

Comment: Part of the problem is that I have very limited access to the server: it's for a school project and the server is on a school server. Can one change his own account authentication type? Or would I need an admin to do that?

Comment: @mikhailvs you'd have to get the School DBA to create a SQL-Server account for you to connect with.  Send him a nice email saying "I love windows, but... ", and make sure to finish it off with lots of <3 and XXXXs.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use sql server integrated authentication with linux, you have to use sql server authentication

Comment: I'm not super sure about how windows authentication works, but do you think there might be a third-party library that does this (I've not found one, but still)? Furthermore, is there a way to force SQL Server authentication, from the client side I mean?

Answer (score 1):

While not a direct answer to your question, this site is useful for almost any connection string question: http://www.connectionstrings.com/.

At the risk of sounding like a commercial: It's your one-stop-shop for connection strings!

Comment: +1, Back in the old days it was wotsits file formats that was the melting part of information.  That was quickly replaced by connectionstrings.com :D